# Golang ParseFloat not accurate in example

Tags: parsing, go

I've been working on a project where I have to convert a string to a uint, to make sure some money values are matching:

```
total, err := strconv.ParseFloat(paymentResp.Transactions[0].Amount.Total, 64)
if err != nil {
    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
}

if o.TotalPrice != uint(total*100) {
    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "Unable to verify amount paid")
}
```

But I've seemingly found a problem when trying to do the `strconv.ParseFloat()` on a couple of numbers, then attempting to multiply them by 100 (to get the cents value).

I've created an example here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MAzkicsnCb0)

```
f, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("79.35", 64)
fmt.Println(uint(f*100))  //7934

f2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("149.20", 64)
fmt.Println(uint(f2*100)) //14919
```

Is `ParseFloat()` what I should be using in this scenario? If not, I'd love to hear a brief explanation on this, as I'm still a programmer in learning.

Comment: [I don't think you should use floats for currency values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Comment: great point, thank you. I'll make a change based off this

Comment: So, for this example - the amount that the API is returning is unfortunately a string. I've done a quick work around (just to have the ability to check if the actual amount is the same as the string amount).
 Example is here: https://play.golang.org/p/7oxqCwX4QSx
I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but this seemed to be the easiest way to get a float that was a string to a uint.
Feel free to add constructive criticism!

Comment: Not sure why this warranted a downvote

Comment: The question is founded on an expectation that binary floats have perfect precision, which they don't. You're seeing rounding which you are causing when converting a float to an int. That's just how floats work; the binary floating-point representation of e.g. decimal `1.23` is not exactly `1.23`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind for when I'm working with Ints and Floats. Very useful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go uses [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) binary floating-point numbers. Floating-point numbers are imprecise. Don't use them for financial transactions. Use integers.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func parseCents(s string) (int64, error) {
    n := strings.SplitN(s, ".", 3)
    if len(n) != 2 || len(n[1]) != 2 {
        err := fmt.Errorf("format error: %s", s)
        return 0, err
    }
    d, err := strconv.ParseInt(n[0], 10, 56)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    c, err := strconv.ParseUint(n[1], 10, 8)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    if d < 0 {
        c = -c
    }
    return d*100 + int64(c), nil
}

func main() {
    s := "79.35"
    fmt.Println(parseCents(s))
    s = "149.20"
    fmt.Println(parseCents(s))
    s = "-149.20"
    fmt.Println(parseCents(s))
    s = "149.2"
    fmt.Println(parseCents(s))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mGuO51QWyIv

Output:

```
7935 <nil>
14920 <nil>
-14920 <nil>
0 format error: 149.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @peterSO's answer, with some bugfix and enhancement:

https://play.golang.org/p/YcRLeEJ7lTA

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func parseCents(s string) (int64, error) {
    var ds string
    var cs string

    n := strings.SplitN(s, ".", 3)
    switch len(n) {
    case 1:
        ds = n[0]
        cs = "0"
    case 2:
        ds = n[0]
        switch len(n[1]) {
        case 1:
            cs = n[1] + "0"
        case 2:
            cs = n[1]
        default:
            return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid format：%s", s)
        }
    default:
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid format：%s", s)
    }

    d, err := strconv.ParseInt(ds, 10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    c, err := strconv.ParseUint(cs, 10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    cents := d * 100

    if strings.HasPrefix(s, "-") {
        cents -= int64(c)
    } else {
        cents += int64(c)
    }

    return cents, nil
}

func main() {
    examples := map[string]int64{
        "79.35": 7935,
        "149.20": 14920,
        "-149.20": -14920,
        "149.2": 14920,
        "-0.12": -12,
        "12": 1200,
        "1.234": 0,
        "1.2.34": 0,
    }

    for s, v := range examples {
        cents, err := parseCents(s)
        fmt.Println(cents, cents == v, err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can split the string, and parse them to an int.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    )

func main() {
    a:=strings.Split("75.35",".")
    if len(a)>2{
    panic("badly formatted price")    
     }
    v,_:=strconv.ParseInt(a[1],10,64)
    w,_:=strconv.ParseInt(a[0],10,64)
   fmt.Println(uint(w*100+v))
}
```

its working in this link https://play.golang.org/p/5s_FTAKSo9M